# Create a new GeoPackage with GeoPackage JS

Tags: geopackage

I'm trying to use [GeoPackage JS](https://ngageoint.github.io/geopackage-js/) to create a new GeoPackage on disk. I haven't been able to find any examples in the docs for how to do this. I did find a method [`GeoPackageAPI.create()`](https://ngageoint.github.io/geopackage-js/api/classes/GeoPackageAPI.html#create) which I tried:

```js
import { GeoPackageAPI } from '@ngageoint/geopackage';

(async () => {
  const gpkg = await GeoPackageAPI.create('/Users/me/test.gpkg');
  let x;
})();
```

and I get `Error: Unable to initialize canvas.`

Has anyone else had more luck doing this?

Comment: Are you using the browser or node? There is a test in https://github.com/ngageoint/geopackage-js/blob/master/test/fixtures/testSetup.js that kind-of does this. Otherwise, maybe an example like https://github.com/ngageoint/geopackage-csv-js/blob/main/index.ts#L95-L119 might help.